# $f$ meromorphic prove that $f$ is not constant

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, mobius-transformation, meromorphic-functions

I'm struggling with the following problem. Any help would be a really welcomed.

> Let $f$ a meromorphic function on $\mathbb C$ s.t $g(w)= f(\frac{1}{w})$ is meromorphic for $w=0$. We say that $f$ is meromorphic over $\hat{ \mathbb C}$.

I  proved that $f$ can be extended to an analytic (i.e continuous) function $\hat{f}:\hat{ \mathbb C}\rightarrow \hat{ \mathbb C}$ but I have some trouble proving:

1. $\hat{f}$ is onto if $f$ is not a constant.
2. If $\hat{f}$ is bijective, then $f$ is a Mobius function.

For 1) I tried using the compactness of $\hat{ \mathbb C}$ and the open mapping theorem but I failed.

For 2) I know that $\hat{f}$ is bijective i.e a holomorphic automorphism of $\hat{ \mathbb C}$ and that if $f$ is Mobius then $f(z)= \frac{ax+b}{cz+d},\forall a,b,c,d\in \mathbb C$ s.t $ac-bd \neq 0$ , but I don't know how I can proceed.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is not constant, it is open. Since its domain ($\hat{\mathbb{C}}$) is compact, $f$ is also closed, so $f(\hat{\mathbb{C}})$ is clopen and not empty, a contradiction since $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is connected: a connected set $A$ cannot have a non empty clopen subset $B$, since otherwise $A=B\sqcup A\backslash B$ with both $B, A\backslash B$ open set.

Since $f$ is meromorphic at $\infty$, it must be a rational function (every non rational function has an essential singularity at $\infty$, can you prove it?). Thus $f=\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$. Let us suppose that $P,Q$ are coprime. Since it is bijective, we can have only one point sent to $\infty$, i.e. one and only one pole, which implies $\text{deg}(Q)\le1$. Similarly, $\#f^{-1}(0)=1$, so $\text{deg}(P)\le 1$. We can now write $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, and it is straightforward to prove that since $f$ is bijective $ad-bc\neq 0$, which gives us the claim.

Comment: $f( \hat{\mathbb{C}})$ is an open right ? I don't see what I can say after $f( \hat{\mathbb{C}}) \neq \emptyset$ . And for the last part yes , I got it we can say that the numerator of f is a linear function either with deg = 1 in $z$ or in $w =\frac{1}{z}$ , we can do the same for $1/f$ because $1/f$ is an automorphism ($\mathbb C$ is it right ? ( Can I have another hint for the first part )

Comment: the image is not empty because the domain is not empty, and so there is at least one element in the image, say $f(1)\in f(\hat{\mathbb{C}})$. $f(\hat{\mathbb{C}})$ is _clopen_ that is it is both open and closed. As another hint: do you know that $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is connected?

Comment: I tried to use the open mapping theorem .. Since $f$ is not constant , also holomorphic s.t $ \hat{\mathbb C}$  is an open connected space , the open mapping theorem states that the image of any open $\in \hat{\mathbb C}$ is open , I don't know what I should do next.

Comment: Should I just assume that since $f(\hat{\mathbb C})\neq \emptyset$  I can find a $w_0 \in f(\hat{\mathbb C})  $ s.t $w_0 = f(z_0) , \; z_0 \in \hat{\mathbb C} $ but how does it prove that $\hat f $ is onto ?

Comment: @mugiwara I edited my answer to adress your doubts. Let me know if it is clear now

Comment: Yes the contradiction is so obvious now .. thanks for your time.